# echo end of url without backslash

Tags: php, echo, explode

http://www.mywebsite/product-tag/animal/

How to I echo animal without the backslash and in big caps like this:

ANIMAL

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = 'http://www.mywebsite/product-tag/animal/';
$parts = explode( '/', $link );
echo(strtoupper($parts[4]));
```

If you want auto searching, then you need to use preg_match.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = 'http://www.mywebsite/product-tag/animal/';
$urlparts = explode("/", $string);

$animal = ($string[strlen($string)-1] == '/'? $urlparts[count($urlparts)-2] : end($urlparts));
echo strtoupper($animal);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually I just figured it out

```
$r = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$r = explode('/', $r);
$r = array_filter($r);
$r = array_merge($r, array()); 

$endofurl = $r[1];
echo $endofurl;
```